# If $\gcd(k, p-1) = 1$ show that $x^k \equiv l \pmod{p}$ has at most one solution.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Assume that $k$ is a natural number and $p$ is a prime where $\gcd(k, p-1) = 1$ Let $l$ be an integer show that 
$x^k \equiv l \pmod{p}$ has at most one solution. I'm pretty sure I have to somehow use the fact that the order of $x$
modulo $p$ is a factor of $p-1$, or possibly the fact that there exists a primitive root modulo $p$ and $l$ is congruent
to some power of that.

Comment: one solution for $x$?

Comment: @Max -  Please prove to us that this is not from a Take-Home exam.

Answer (score 2):

If $l \equiv 0 \bmod p$, then $x^k \equiv 0 \bmod p$ and so $x \equiv 0 \bmod p$.

Otherwise, write $1 = ku+(p-1)v$.

Then $x \equiv x^{ku+(p-1)v} \equiv (x^k)^u (x^{p-1})^v \equiv l^u \equiv (y^k)^u (y^{p-1})^v \equiv y^{ku+(p-1)v} \equiv y \bmod p$.

---

If you can use group theory, then $x \mapsto x^k$ is a group homomorphism $U(p) \mapsto U(p)$ which is injective because $x^k \equiv 1 \bmod p$ implies that $ord(x)$ divides both $k$ and $p-1$, and so divides their gcd, which is $1$.